# How to align checkboxes in a form that they are among themselfs?

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon,

i strugle to align checkboxes vertically. I started with a form project as beginner project.

I have them all inline but would like that they are vertically among themselfs so that the for labels are not next to each other.

I tried with flexbox, display and and with align-text. But i got stuck and nothing is working.

Can someone help me please?

```css
/* first div class with h1 elemnt */
.a {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

/* text of survey in first div */
.schrift {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

/*body */
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

/* second div with p elemnt descriping the survey */
.description {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;

  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* p elemnt in second div  just the class of the text */
.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* third div */
.questions {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Building my headline in a div with a border -->
    <div class="a">
      <h1 class="schrift">Survey</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Describing the survey in a new div and p element-->
    <div class="description">
      <p class="text">
        In this Survey we are going to find out how you rate Universities and if
        there are other ways of learning then the university way
      </p>
    </div>

    <!--Building a new div for the question with the checkboxes -->

    <div class="questions">
      <p>1. How satisfied are you at university?</p>
      <form class="form">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="love" value="loving" />
          I love it
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ok" value="ok" />
          It is OK
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="boring" value="boring" />
          It is boring
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="hate" value="hate" />
          I hate it
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help you

```css
/* first div class with h1 elemnt */
.a {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

/* text of survey in first div */
.schrift {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: antiquewhite;
}

/*body */
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

/* second div with p elemnt descriping the survey */
.description {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;

  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* p elemnt in second div  just the class of the text */
.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* third div */
.questions {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.bounding {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.check-box {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Building my headline in a div with a border -->
    <div class="a">
      <h1 class="schrift">Survey</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Describing the survey in a new div and p element-->
    <div class="description">
      <p class="text">
        In this Survey we are going to find out how you rate Universities and if
        there are other ways of learning then the university way
      </p>
    </div>

    <!--Building a new div for the question with the checkboxes -->

    <div class="questions">
      <p>1. How satisfied are you at university?</p>
      <form class="form">
        <label class="bounding">
          <input class ="check-box" type="checkbox" name="love" value="loving" />
          I love it
        </label>
        <label class="bounding">
          <input class ="check-box" type="checkbox" name="ok" value="ok" />
          It is OK
        </label>

        <label class="bounding">
          <input class ="check-box" type="checkbox" name="boring" value="boring" />
          It is boring
        </label>

        <label class="bounding">
          <input class ="check-box" type="checkbox" name="hate" value="hate" />
          I hate it
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]